# How to concat two columns data in one inside SET

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

I need to concat two columns. I tried as follows,

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @sql nvarchar(200)

SET @sql =
'SELECT UserId,CONCAT(CONVERT([varchar](50) ,DECRYPTBYKEY(FirstName)),CONVERT([varchar](50),DECRYPTBYKEY(LastName))) AS [Userfullname]  from [user] WHERE  FkSupervisor in ('
+ @selectedSupervisorIds
+ ') AND IsActive = 1'

EXECUTE Sp_executesql
  @sql
```

This works fine but output as follows,

```
UserId  Userfullname
10397   jhonewal
10422   funnyman
10428   Zeroowl
```

How can I add space between first name and last name?

Expected output,

```
UserId  Userfullname
10397   jhone wal
10422   funny man
10428   Zero owl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CONCAT` allows concatenation of up to 254 parameters. Simply add the spaces as extra parameters where you would like them added:

```
SET @sql =
'SELECT UserId, CONCAT(CONVERT([varchar](50), DECRYPTBYKEY(FirstName)), '' '', CONVERT([varchar](50), DECRYPTBYKEY(LastName))) AS [Userfullname]  from [user] WHERE  FkSupervisor in ('
+ @selectedSupervisorIds
+ ') AND IsActive = 1'

EXECUTE Sp_executesql
   @sql
```

Comment: I tried it, it shows following error
`An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'IsAc'`

Comment: Double check the `WHERE` clause on that string. It sounds as though you might have `IsAc` instead of `IsActive = 1`

Comment: Yes I checked it , I typed without any missing part, but its still not working, so then I copy pasted your code. same error occured

Comment: How's the `DECLARE` for `@sql`? Is it long enough to take all of the resulting string. You can use `SELECT LEN()` on the string to check that there won't be truncation of the result.

Comment: Updated the question, that's how I declare it . is it the problem?

Comment: Yes that the reason, Thank you :)

Comment: No worries, it's all about hammering away at one thing at a time until it works :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also add the spaces between firstName and lastName without using the `CONCAT` function. 
Please check the below query:

```
SET @sql =
'SELECT UserId, (CONVERT([varchar](50), DECRYPTBYKEY(FirstName)) + '' '' + CONVERT([varchar](50), DECRYPTBYKEY(LastName))) AS [Userfullname]  from [user] WHERE  FkSupervisor in ('
+ @selectedSupervisorIds
+ ') AND IsActive = 1'

EXECUTE Sp_executesql
  @sql
```